# how to use @SequenceGenerator in spring

Tags: spring, jpa

how to use @SequenceGenerator in Spring

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

That's to say, `javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator` has nothing to do with Spring what so ever; it's JPA (Hibernate, Toplink, ...); e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION")
public class Application {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "APPLICATION_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "APPLICATION_SEQ", sequenceName = "APPLICATION_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
private Integer id;
```